# What am I doing wrong using functions with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# define path of driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def mainloop():
    driver.get("https://www.nitrotype.com/login")
    login(username, password)

# LOGGING IN

def login(username, password):
    time.sleep(2)
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
    username.send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(1)
    password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
    username.send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(1)
    password.send_keys(password, Keys.RETURN)


mainloop()
```

when I run this, it shows me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stevek/Projects/Python/nitrotype-bot/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    mainloop()
  File "/home/stevek/Projects/Python/nitrotype-bot/main.py", line 10, in mainloop
    login(username, password)
  File "/home/stevek/Projects/Python/nitrotype-bot/main.py", line 17, in login
    username.send_keys(username)
  File "/home/stevek/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "/home/stevek/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

I'm so confused. I didn't use any XPaths.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nitrotype.com/login")
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
username.send_keys(username)
password.send_keys(password, Keys.RETURN)
```

When I didn't use functions, like this, it runs as expected. It logins. No functions.
What's wrong?
Also, note that I replaced all username with variables.

Comment: Before you continue, I would like to say one thing. If you are trying to create a bot that does this typing race for you I can assure you,that you will get banned. I can say that because I have tried this myself. I even set the `wpm` to 65 which i'd say is average and still got banned. Sail carefully my guy.

Comment: The stack trace error message is referencing this line of code: `for i in range(len(val)):` which is not present in the code you are showing us, so it will be hard for us to help.  Also you are doing `send_keys` to `username` twice

Comment: @JD2775 if you look at the line above it tells you where it's coming from - a file in `site-packages`, which means it's part of Selenium, not the user's code.

Comment: @MattDMo.  Ah, my mistake.  Thanks

Comment: @BuddyBob just use pyautogui.

Comment: @JD277 The code on line 139-152 shows https://pastebin.com/6xq7M32U

Comment: Have you tried removing the duplicate `username.send_keys(username)` as I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: @JD2775 fixed it by using all XPAThs

Answer (score 1):

You are passing variable names into `login()` that have the same name as the variables you are defining for the web elements within that function.  You can't do that.

Change them to something different, like below `user` and `pw`

```
def mainloop():
    driver.get("https://www.nitrotype.com/login")
    login("test", "testPW")

# LOGGING IN

def login(user, pw):
    time.sleep(2)
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
    username.send_keys(user)
    time.sleep(1)
    password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
    time.sleep(1)
    password.send_keys(pw, Keys.RETURN)


mainloop()
```

I also removed the duplicate `username.send_keys(user)` in the function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overwriting the `username` parameter passed into the method with a WebElement then passing that to `.send_keys()` which is expecting a string.

```
def login(username, password):
          ^ username parameter is a string
    username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
    ^ username is overwritten with a WebElement here
```

In your method, you don't need to assign the elements to a variable. The whole method can be simplified down to two lines,

```
def login(username, password):
    driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(username, Keys.RETURN)
```

I also removed all of the sleeps because they likely aren't needed. Best practice when you need a wait is to use [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Also, your final code with no method wouldn't work either because of the same reason.

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
^ this is a WebElement
username.send_keys(username)
^ this is a WebElement
                   ^ this is a WebElement but should be a string.
```

You likely hardcoded the `.send_keys()` string but replaced it when you "replaced all username with variables."